# Is batch size of 8 too small to train imagenet data?

Tags: image, neural-network, deep-learning, batch-processing

I wish to try to train imagenet from scratch. However, my spu only support batch size of 8. From most papers and github repo, most people seem to use batch size of more than 8. Can I know if this is too small? Right now, I am unable to get result with it.

Comment: This is depending on tons of things and your question is lacking a lot. *I am unable to get result with it* is also kind of useless. Ignoring the environment: batch-size of 8 is fine; but convergence speed might differ. It's also important then to tune learning-rates (instead of copying them from the papers).

Comment: why is stack overflow full of noobs who downvotes a question when they dont know the answer?

Comment: You tell me. (1) Read your question again and evaluate if it's a good one (not even 3 lines, no links or references, nothing). (2) Then read my comment and maybe it would be a good idea to process it and react somehow (some other way than firing shots). (3) As you seem to have some math background, you should know, that in non-convex optimization not much is guaranteed. This is the reason why such broad questions can't be answered in a simple and general manner (e.g. convex setting: yeah sure, batch-size=1 even has the best theoretical guarantees).So its even more imporant to give alot of info

Comment: @sascha so you are saying all the people who get good results are just lucky and so they dont deserved it since no science involved?

Comment: No. They tuned their parameters by good experiment-setup / cross-validation (science!) and after years of work they got some intuition (hardly packed into proofs). But guarantees are tough. While i really don't like your attitude, checkout pages 17-19 of [this tutorial](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~yann/talks/lecun-ranzato-icml2013.pdf). Of course this tuning-process works much better when you got all the data and code in front of you and don't have to reside to some partial-info within a short SO-post. That's the relevant part here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on some factors:

- The architecture you are using, some architectures work better with higher batch size others not.
- The memory available, in several times, using lots of examples per batch is better but you are limited by the memory available (using CPU or GPU)
- The training time. If you can train your model per days per weeks or only a set of hours can give you an idea how many epoch and batch size is better.

As you see it's difficult to answer a specific number that's the reason why researchers try with differents parameter to analyze how this will impact the final model.